# Python - get object with latest date as a value to attribute in list

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, data-structures

I have following class structure

```
class Member:
    
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.member_id = id
        self.items = []
        
class Item:
    
    def __init__(self, id, name, last_updated):
        self.item_id = id
        self.last_updated = last_updated
        self.name = name
```

I have a dictionary where I have list of Member objects for each key (it is generated based on some condition but it is something like nlm123, npl334, etc.). So the sample looks like thisL

```
{
    "nlm123": [
        {
            "member_id": 1,
            "items": [
                {
                    "item_id": "1",
                    "last_updated": "2020-10-31 10:05:17",
                    "name": "shirt"
                },
                {
                    "item_id": "2",
                    "last_updated": "2020-10-30 10:05:17",
                    "name": "shirt_shirt"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "member_id": 2,
            "items": [
                {
                    "item_id": "1",
                    "last_updated": "2020-11-01 10:05:17",
                    "name": "shirt"
                },
                {
                    "item_id": "2",
                    "last_updated": "2020-11-04 10:05:17",
                    "name": "shirt_shirt"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want an efficient way to iterate items of dictionary and identify object of Member which have the latest updated item based on `last_updated`  attribute. In my current implementation I end up using three for loops which I think is not the ideal solution. Output should be an object with "member_id": 2 because it has the latest updated item.

Comment: why not iterating through your dict and save the first "last_updated". After that just iterate (in the same for loop) through all other entries and check, if this one is newer. If yes, take this object, if not, check the next object. if you finished your loop you know which one is the newest in your dict

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see this being possible without three loops, I guess you have something like this?

```py
from datetime import datetime

def get_last_updated_member(data):
    latest = None
    last_updated = None
    for members in data.values():
        for member in members:
            for item in member["items"]:
                item_updated = datetime.strptime(item["last_updated"], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
                if not last_updated or item_updated > last_updated:
                    last_updated = item_updated
                    latest = member
    return latest
```

We can't do much else except some tricks to flatten out the code a bit:

```py
import itertools
from datetime import datetime

def get_last_updated_member(data):
    latest = None
    last_updated = None
    all_members = itertools.chain.from_iterable(data.values())
    member_items = ((member, item) for member in all_members for item in member["items"])
    for member, item in member_items:
        item_updated = datetime.strptime(item["last_updated"], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        if not last_updated or item_updated > last_updated:
            last_updated = item_updated
            latest = member
    return latest
```

We make use of two [generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators). This version is no more efficient than the original one (we iterate through the same number of items), but it's not worse either (we still only iterate through everything once and don't build any intermediate data structures).

The first generator is `itertools.chain.from_iterable(data.values())` which flattens the `data` dict by concatenating the members lists from each entry.

The second generator is `((member, item) for member in all_members for item in member["items"])` ...it looks like list comprehension syntax but with `(...)` instead of `[...]`. This is called a "generator expression".  This one basically gives us a convenient way to access the current parent `member` while iterating over all the `items`.

So now we can iterate over our generator and we only have one level of explicit `for` loop. The inner code of the loop is the same as before.

Here is another alternative, using the `reduce` function from `functools`:

```py
import itertools
from datetime import datetime
from functools import reduce


def get_last_updated_member(data):
    all_members = itertools.chain.from_iterable(data.values())
    member_last_updated = (
        (member, datetime.strptime(item["last_updated"], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
        for member in all_members
        for item in member["items"]
    )
    def reducer(result, current):
        if not result[1] or current[1] > result[1]:
            return current
        return result
    member, last_updated = reduce(reducer, member_last_updated, (None, None))
    return member
```

Here we amend the generator to to return tuples of: `(member, item_updated): Tuple[dict, datetime]` (we could have done this in the previous version too). Then the `reduce` function iterates through the generator, applying the `reducer` function that we defined to compare each item with the current best match and return the new best match. When the generator is exhausted `reduce` returns the final best match to our code.

Arguably the original version is more readable than either of the latter two, despite the pythonic principle of "flat is better than nested".